# How to switch redirect status code from 308 to 301 when there is no trailing slash in the end of URL

Tags: node.js, web, redirect

I have node js server and when I try to my domain like www.mysite/en-de (without slash) I get 308 redirect

What I need to change to have 301 status code in case of lack trailing slash?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I came up with

```
 const middleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next) => {
  try {
    const test = /^(https?:\/\/)?(?:.*\/)?[^\/.]+$/.test(req.url);

    if (req.url.substr(-1) !== '/' && req.url.length > 1 && test) {
      res.redirect(301, `${req.url}/`);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } catch (err) {
  }
};

app.use(middleware);
```

Comment: this does not work